# How do I Resize Margins Based on the Width of Screen?

Tags: html, css, media

I have this HTML and CSS code for a webpage. I am trying to make the website mobile-friendly and resizes itself with the size of screen viewed. I want the margins to become very small when viewed on a narrow screen like a smartphone and readjusts itself gradually when the screen is bigger and margins become larger and larger until it is a full screen of, say, a desktop computer.  However, this code isn't really working. (I didn't include all the other CSS parts of this code, but please ask for it if needed!)

***My attempt to resize margins due to the width of the screen:***

```
        @media (max-width: 1100px, min-width: 800px) {
            body {
                margin-right: 20px;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }

        @media (max-width: 750px, min-width: 501) {
            body {
                margin-right: 5vw;
                margin-left: 5vw;
            }
        }   
        @media (max-width: 500px) {
            body {
                margin-right: 2vw;
                margin-left: 2vw;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>

        <h1>Blog</h1>
        <ul> <!-- Menu Tabs -->
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```

Thanks, I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Run your CSS though a CSS syntax checker or linter.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace around your first media query. Also, you have some extra bits in your media queries making them invalid. The way media queries work makes the `min-width` parts you were trying to add unnecessary. The following code, at large screens, creates a `20px` left/right margin. When the threshold of `750px` is hit, `5vw` kicks in, and so on.

```
/* Invalid: 
   @media (max-width: 1100px, min-width: 800px) 
*/

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  body {
    margin-right: 5vw;
    margin-left: 5vw;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    margin-right: 2vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
  }
}
```

If your intention is to start with a default `20px` right/left margin, for screens even larger than `1100px`, you could create a default margin in your CSS which will be overridden by your media query rules. Then, you can begin your media queries at a narrower screen size.

```
/* default size */
body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-rights: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  body {
    margin-right: 5vw;
    margin-left: 5vw;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    margin-right: 2vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5vez3rdc/

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I removed the  `, min-width` bits, since they are extraneous.

Comment: What was wrong with them and if he wanted to keep them for some reason how should he fix them?

Comment: @torazaburo I expanded my answer to explain the issues and the solution.